# How to I get Github to notify me of review requests?

Tags: github

My coworkers request me to review their Pull Requests, but I can't tell which ones. Is there a way to get Github to alert me when this occurs?

I see there is a Review Requested filter in the Notifications section, but that never shows anything. There doesn't seem to be any specific setting for this in the Settings section either. Nor do I get any emails.

Is there anyway to set this up?

Comment: https://github.com/settings/notifications

Answer (score 10):

1. Navigate to https://github.com/settings/notifications
2. Scroll down to the `Email notification preferences` section
3. Ensure your `Default notification email` is set to an email address you can receive email at.
4. Ensure `Pull Request reviews` is turned on

If those steps do not work, check your spam folder. You may also want to make sure that a different email address isn't specified in the `Custom routing` section.

Answer (score 4):

Some section's name has been changed since the popular answer, if you are looking for a solution on 2023 and after please see below.

Firstly, navigate to Github Notifications Settings here => https://github.com/settings/notifications and follow below screenshots

Step - 1: Go to Subscriptions section
[image]

Step - 2: Check 'Email' on Participating, @mentions and custom section
[image]

Step - 3: Check your required options on Customize email updates section
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answer:

Make sure to tick `Email` checkbox in `Participating` section, otherwise `Email notification preferences` section won't show up below.

[image]